# how to understand the (f+g)(x) and (αf)(x) notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In the following notations:
$$ (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) $$
$$ (αf+βg)(x)=αf(x)+βg(x) $$

can anyone help to understand:

$$(f+g)(x) $$
$$ (αf+βg)(x) $$

?

It's no problem if $f$ and $g$ are linear transformation matrices $A$ and $B$ and $x$ is a vector variable $X$ because I can compute and compare $(A+B)X$ and $AX+BX$.

Otherwise, when it's non-linear, the notation is hard to understand.

for example,

$$ f(x)=\cos x+1 $$
$$ g(x)=e^x-2 $$

I can write:
$$ f(x)+g(x)=\cos x+1 + e^x-2 $$
$$ αf(x)+βg(x) = α\cdot \cos x+α + β\cdot e^x -2β$$

In this case, what are the definition of (and how to evaluate):

$$(f+g)(x) $$
$$ (αf+βg)(x) $$

?

I'm asking this in order to understand the definition of dual space ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space)) which suggests $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(αf+βg)(x)=αf(x)+βg(x)$ are to be proved/verified (note the word "satisfying" the conditions)

Comment: If $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and $f(x)+g(x) = \cos x + \sin x + m + n$, then surely $(f+g)(x) = \cos x + \sin x + m + n$. If $a=b$, and $b=c$, then $a=c$. (Equality is [*transitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).)

Comment: The referenced statement is still giving a definition, it's just loosely using the word "satisfying" to mean that the addition and scalar multiplication are defined to be the *unique* operations satisfying those equations.  (But then, once you have defined those, you can indeed ask to prove based on those definitions that the compound operation of linear combination satisfies the equation $(\alpha f + \beta g)(x) = \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)$.)

Comment: And, I guess there is still something to prove within the definitions themselves: e.g. that there exists an addition $V^* \times V^* \to V^*$ satisfying the equation; and then to prove the uniqueness as well (which is very easy).  In essence, the major point is to show that if $f$ and $g$ are both linear, then the function $x \mapsto f(x) + g(x)$ is also linear.  And similarly for the scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I noticed that the definition is restricted to "the set of all linear maps" (linear functionals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f+g$ is the function defined by
$$
(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)
$$
for all $x$. So '$f+g$' is just a name we give to a function—but it is a meaningful name, since when people talk of the function '$f+g$' I immediately know what function they are talking about. But if you don't like this notation, then you could just call this function something else instead. E.g. you could let $h$ be the function defined by
$$
h(x)=f(x)+g(x) \, .
$$
It's important to distinguish between a function and its values: $f$ is the function, whereas $f(x)$ is the function evaluated at an arbitrary point $x$. When people speak of 'the function $f(x)$', you should keep in mind that this is just an imprecise yet convenient shorthand. It's the same story with the function $f+g$. The function $f+g$ has the property that when it is evaluated at an arbitrary point $x$,
$$
(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) \, .
$$
Hopefully from this you can guess the meaning of $f \cdot g$ as well: it's the function with the property that
$$
(f \cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) \, .
$$
Sometimes we write simply $fg$ to mean $f \cdot g$, but this notation can be ambiguous since $fg$ can also denote the composite function $f \circ g$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical way to define an operation on a space of functions "point-wise". A function $f:X\to Y$ between two sets $X$ and $Y$ is given by $\{ (x,f(x)) : x\in X \}$; i.e. by giving its values at every point $x$. Now given two functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$, you may define
$$
(\alpha\cdot f + \beta\cdot g) :=\{ (x, \alpha\cdot f(x) + \beta\cdot g(x)):x\in X\}
$$
which is precisely what is meant by saying that $\alpha\cdot f + \beta\cdot g$ is defined as
$$
(\alpha\cdot f + \beta\cdot g)(x) := \alpha\cdot f(x) + \beta\cdot g(x).
$$
The above notation is slightly abusive because the quantifier is left out; it is implicit. The definition intends to say that you make this definition *for every $x\in X$*, thereby defining the whole function.

More generally, if you have any $k$-ary operation $\omega: Y^k\to Y$ on a set $Y$, you can extend this operation to the space of maps $Y^X$ for any set $X$. Indeed, for $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in Y^X$ you define
$$
\omega(f_1,\ldots,f_k) := \{ (x, \omega(f_1(x),\ldots,f_k(x)) : x\in X \}
$$
This is referred to as defining $\omega$ point-wise on $Y^X$.

Comment: Thank you for the extended definition.